# How can I use sympy sum over elements of a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sympy

I am just trying to use a sympy sum over a list of elements, for example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]

expression = sympy.sum(x[i], (i,0,2)) * sympy.sum(x[j], (j,1,3))
```

and I just want it to numerically evaluate this. I always get index out of range, although it's clearly not out of range. Any ideas?

Comment: @Julien thank you for your reply, however it lacks utility. The example I put above IS a minimal reproducible example, which you would have seen if you would have added an "import sympy" in front of it and tried to run....

Comment: No it's not even with `import`

Comment: Maybe because it gives an error? ...

Comment: It gives many errors, none of which are the one you mention. [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to build a symbolic expression representing your summation:

```py
from sympy import *
x = IndexedBase("x")
i, j = symbols("i, j")
expr = Sum(x[i], (i,0,2)) * Sum(x[j], (j,1,3))
```

Then, you can substitute `x` with your "array":

```py
xv = [1,2,3,4,5]
expr.subs(x, Array(xv)).doit()
```

Note that I converted `xv` into a SymPy's Array, otherwise the procedure won't work.

EDIT: added clarification

If your list is composed of hundres, or thousands or millions of entries, then it's better to convert the symbolic expression to a lambda function in order to improve evaluation speed:

```py
f = lambdify(x, expr)
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(f))
# def _lambdifygenerated(Dummy_26):
#     return (builtins.sum(Dummy_26[i] for i in range(0, 2+1)))*(builtins.sum(Dummy_26[j] for j in range(1, 3+1)))

f(xv)
# 54
```

Comment: It is possible to handle this in a very clever way with integer multiplication as discussed [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/25018).